# Not fully working jQuery script which changes div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so my problem is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hskhu/

When i click "Rejestracja" Link, it changes content of div, but after this when i try to click "logowanie" link nothing matters, i dont know why can someone help me? all divs with contents of Rejestracja and logowanie are under html with display:none atribute

JS here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#change').click(function(){
            var $which = $(this).html();
            var $wyjmij = $('#' + $which).html();
            $('#loginbox').html($wyjmij);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, jQuery only selects the first element with a specific ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding an event to the element with the id `#change`. You are replacing the element when the link is clicked, meaning the current bound event has no valid target.

You need to bind the event to a closer static element and delegate the event to the `#change`.

You can do this using `on()`.
Check the section on `Direct and delegated events` in the [**on() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Change your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginbox").on("click", "#change", function(){
        var $which = $(this).html();
        var $wyjmij = $('#' + $which).html();
        $('#loginbox').html($wyjmij);
    });
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hskhu/2/) - Using dynamic bindings by binding to `#loginbox` targeting `#change`